# Define a macro with defined(X)

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Here is a macro I want to use, if `X_DEFINED` is defined it will be evaluated to DEFAULT_X otherwise it will be evaluated to `x`

```
#define GET_X(x) (defined(X_DEFINED) ? DEFAULT_X : x)
```

It doesn't compile, with the error

```
error: 'X_DEFINED' was not declared in this scope
```

Any suggestions? I want to be able to select between a parameter and a global variable based on if `X_DEFINED` was defined or not

Comment: suggestion: Let us know what you actually want to use this for so we can tell you how to do it without macros

Comment: btw this line alone does not produce any error. Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`defined()` only works in `#if` and similar preprocessor directives.

You want something like this:

```
#ifdef X_DEFINED
#define GET_X(x) DEFAULT_X
#else
#define GET_X(x) x
#endif
```

Comment: Re: "`defined()` only works in `#if`" -- indeed. And the code could be written with `#if defined(X_DEFINED)` as well as with `#ifdef X_DEFINED`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define 2 different macros, depending on whether `X_DEFINED` is defined:

```
#ifdef X_DEFINED
#   define GET_X(x) x
#else
#   define GET_X(x) DEFAULT_X
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Sloppy speaking you are mixing runtime stuff (evaluation of a ternary operator) with stuff that happens even before compilation (preprocessor). You can use `#ifdef` instead:

```
#ifdef X_DEFINED
    #define GET_X(x) DEFAULT_X
#else
    #define GET_X(x) x
#endif
```